# Searching sum of constants in a polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+ax+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. If $f(x+1004)$ leaves a remainder of $36$ upon division by $x+1005$, and $f(x+1005)$ leaves a remainder of $42$ upon division by $x+1004$, what is the value of $a+b$?

Comment: The remainders shall hold for all $x$?

Comment: What have you tried as far as work?  Did you attempt any computations with $\frac{f(x+1004)}{x+1005}$ and the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general knowledge to be used is that if

$$P(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+R$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials and $R$ a constant. Then, evaluating on $x=a$ we get $P(a)=R$. This is called the [Polynomial remainder theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)

You are looking for $f(1)-1=a+b$.

We  have that $f(x+1005)$ gives remainder $42$ after division by $x+1004=x-(-1004)$. This means that $f(-1004+1005)=f(1)=1+a+b=42$.

From this we get that $a+b=41$.

Answer (score 4):

By assumption we have
$$f(x+1004)=(x+1005)Q(x)+36\tag{1}$$
and
$$f(x+1005)=(x+1004)S(x)+42\tag{2}$$
so let $x=-1005$ in $(1)$ gives $$f(-1)=-1-a+b=36$$
and let $x=-1004$ in $(2)$ gives
$$f(1)=1+a+b=42$$
hence 
$$a=2\quad,\quad b=39$$

Comment: excellent, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** From the given information $$f(x+1004)=36+(x+1005)b_{1}(x)\\
f(x+1005)=42+(x+1004)b_{2}(x)$$
So, $$f(-1)=-a+b-1=36\\
f(1)=a+b+1=42$$

Comment: You have a typo in $f(-1)$: should be $-a+b-1=36$.

Comment: Oh! sorry. I've edited now.